# Update listview single item after getting the response from serve in Android

Tags: android, listview, chat

I am working on a chat application, the chat functionality is working fine but I need to show the sent message delivery status to the sender. I am getting a status response from the server with message id and corresponding delivery status, now the issue is I am not able to update the status of a single item in the listview.

Due to low reputation I am not able to attach any screenshot here.

Comment: But your reputation is enough to post some code ;)

Comment: get Array position of listview then update your array from status response server, then notifyDataSetChanged() of your adapter

Answer (score 2):

At the time of getting the status and msdId , you can notifyDataSetChanged() of the adapter before this line you can call adapter method in which you show the sent message delivery status and also you have to maintain the listview current positions.

Comment: thanx for your response. I am storing the messages in an Arraylist and updating the status based upon the msg_id, but if I use notifyDataSetChanged() the entire list is getting refreshed..... but I want to only update a single item in the list. This behavior is there in the current Whatsapp application. Is there anyway to refresh only one item in the listview?

Comment: Whatsapp also refresh the entire list but the fact is that it maintains the list position so that it won't look like refreshing the entire list.

Comment: thanx again. Will give it a try.

Comment: Your answer is working but notable to maintain the current scroll postion. I am using the below code to save the postion                                                                                                         firstVisibleItem = mMsgListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
oldCount = mListAdapter.getCount();
View view = mListView.getChildAt(0);
position = (view == null ? 0 :  view.getBottom()- mListView.getPaddingBottom());

Comment: and the below code to re postion
mListView.setSelectionFromTop(firstVisibleItem + mListAdapter.getCount() - oldCount+1, position);
I have added a header for the listview, not sure if thats the reason for the issue.

Comment: // save index and top position
            index = mMsgListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View v = mMsgListView.getChildAt(0);
            top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - list.getPaddingTop());
 //After adapter NotifyDatasetChanged :
// Restore list last position
                mMsgListView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);

Comment: Hi @Shivani Gupta thanks for the code but It's still not working for me. The restored position is not exactly same, it moves up by one item. I am using reverse listview (android:stackFromBottom="true"  android:transcriptMode="normal")  with header view. Do I need to consider the header view?

Comment: yea i think. So just you have to -1 or +1 to the index and try ... I dont think so reverse listview effects this code